# Realm sort() - sorting based on string or int

Tags: android, sorting, realm, realm-mobile-platform

Realm sort has ascending or descending sort. But I wanna sort the list based on an id where that matching id should come on the top of the list and the rest should be at the bottom.

```
        realmResults.where().sort("Id",12);
```

**List : 6,8,7,4,....**

**expected sort for 4 : 4,6,8,7,...**

Comment: That doesn't look sorted to me at all :D explains why this isn't something that is natively supported

Comment: But for me to short this I had to loop list to check for a match and list it. If it was a query it would have been much easier.

Comment: Technically what I'd do is have a separate highlighted element above the actual list, and the list below could have a query that is unsorted, but the highlighted element is removed with `realm.where().not().equalTo().findAll()`.